# Deploy ASP.NET Core to IIS on TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, asp.net-core

I would like to setup automatic builds for my vNext project and deploy to IIS. In Visual Studio, we use the publish option, but is a way to do this from the command line and integrate with TeamCity.